# Failed to intialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting below error when I tried to run the query.

> Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

1. I verified, SQL agent user has sufficient privileges
2. I already passed the command to run the query in msdb database
3. Do I need to pass `@query_result_width` parameter?

Please help me fix the problem.

```
USE msdb
GO

EXEC sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'TESTSQL Database Mail',
      @recipients = 'Helpdesk@test.org',
      @subject = 'XXX Doc Entries Missing From COI Arch. Doc. Table',
      @body = 'The list of documents below are missing from the COI Archived Document Table.',
      @execute_query_database = 'msdb',
      @query =  '
SELECT 
     di.[id]
    ,di.[infotext]
    ,di.[creationtime]
    ,di.userstate
    ,ns.doctype
    ,ns.arcencldescr
    ,ns.arcenclcat 
    ,ns.referenceno
    ,ns.contactno
    ,ns.custno
    ,ns.docno
    ,ns.employno
    ,ns.jobno
    ,ns.positionno
    ,ns.purchreqno
    ,ns.vendno
INTO
    #navarchive
FROM 
    [BF1000].[dbo].[DocInfo] di
JOIN
    [BF1000].[dbo].[NaviStandard] ns ON di.id = ns.docid
WHERE
    di.userstate = 2502
    AND ns.referenceno like "AR%"
    AND arcenclcat <> "APP"
select
     na.id as "Doc. ID"
    ,na.referenceno as "Arch. Ref. No."
    ,na.infotext as "Doc. Info."
    ,na.doctype as "Doc. Type"
from
    #navarchive na
left join
    ESOERPNAV_Live.dbo.[ESO$COI Archived Doc_] ad
on
    na.id = ad.[COI Doc ID]
where
    ad.[COI Doc ID] is null
and
    na.id > 505745
order by
    na.id
drop table #navarchive              '
```

Comment: SQLCMD defaults to quoted identifiers off for backwards compatibility.  Specify the `-I` argument to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: The OP appears to be already relying on non-ANSI behaviour, @DanGuzman : `ns.referenceno like "AR%"` Unless, Maddy, you do have a column named `[AR%]`? I *hope* not.

Comment: More likely the problem is that the query you're trying to execute is failing; we can't run your query, but I suspect if you copy it out, and try to run it (with `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` set) you'll get an error.

Comment: @ThomA, I just noticed that too, Should be sinlge-quites (`ns.referenceno like 'AR%'`). The double-quotes surrounding column aliases are ok with quoted identifier on.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yeah I tried with quoted identifier setting, but no luck

Comment: Yeah, but DBMail defaults to `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`, @DanGuzman . If, for example, you try `@query = N'SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE "m%";'` the email would send.

Comment: @ThomA you are right, we don't have a column named AR%

Comment: @Maddy, did you try `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;`  in the `SELECT` query batch?